# Do I need to install SQL Server on client machine?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm creating a console application for the customer, using VS2010 which comes with SQL Server 2008 included.

I wanted to deploy that application on client's machine in order to check. I wanted to know do I need to have database installed on my client's machine?

Comment: The database must be installed **somwhere** where your client's machine can connect to; possibly on his machine, possibly on a server in his network - whatever you choose - but there **must be** a SQL Server **somewhere** for the client's machine to use

Comment: If you use a database, then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: Note, "install SQL Server" is itself a bit ambiguous - there are multiple versions of SQL Server - some don't need installation; some (express) that have a *light* install that can be included in an installer, and some full-weight dedicated server versions that should be installed properly and on dedicated hardware.

Comment: @marc_s: Your comment really should be an answer. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to sql server database mdf file without installing sql server on client machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054905/connecting-to-sql-server-database-mdf-file-without-installing-sql-server-on-clie)

Answer (score 3):

The SQL Server database must be installed **somewhere** where your client's machine can connect to:

- possibly on his machine (if this is just a trial, for instance)
- possibly on a server in his network (if multiple users in his organization will want to use the data)
- possibly in the cloud (think: SQL Azure)

Whatever you choose - but there **must be** a SQL Server **somewhere** for the client's machine to use, if your application uses SQL Server to store its data....

Answer (score 1):

If you use a file based database, you don't need to install it anywhere for the client to use it. However, the file based database is probably not as scalable and may have other disadvantages.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564073/what-is-the-difference-between-a-file-based-database-and-a-server-based-database) is a good explanation of the difference between a file based and server based database.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your Sql server only on SERVER machine. In connection string you specify path of Server machine. you dont need to install Sql on each client machine.